# Design considerations before deployment to AWS?

Tags: node.js, spring, amazon-web-services

Looking to create a new webapp with a Node.js front end, Spring at the back end, and a database I haven't decided on yet! Primarily, the objective of the exercise is to improve my working knowledge by doing: it's a side project. If it then evolves into being useful for others, that's a bonus.

So, deployment to the Cloud on AWS makes sense for this use case? Especially true if the webapp ends up being useful for nothing other than a learning experience, given that AWS cost is based on usage?

There is one question I do have before diving into the Amazon Free Tier to exercise my theory, though: are there some design considerations that should be made to mitigate AWS costs? Or would those considerations be cloud agnostic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> deployment to the Cloud on AWS makes sense for this use case

The benefit of using the cloud is the simplicity to provision resources, so you can test your stack as soon as they are ready.

It makes sense if your target is to learn using the cloud, it doesn't make sense if you will spend tons of time learning the cloud when it should not be your focus.

> are there some design considerations that should be made to mitigate AWS costs? Or would those considerations be cloud agnostic?

Again, it depends. If your company is going to all-in a single cloud provider, it probably saves more money for a cloud-specific design because it can make use of all the managed service. If your company (usually enterprise) plans to use multiple clouds for whatever reasons (e.g. disaster recovery, cost negotiation, etc.), then your design should be cloud agnostic, of course.

However, the term "cloud agnostic" is very tricky. It actually depends on how much you can afford (e.g. money, time, expertise, etc.) to migrate from one cloud to another. For example, if you use the managed Kubernetes, it is easier to migrate between clouds because most of the clouds provide the same service. If you use AWS Fargate instead, the exit costs might be higher because the setup will be quite different on another cloud.